# EWS api load() on FileAttachment linux/mono base64 decode gives wrong output

Tags: web-services, mono, exchangewebservices

EWS 1.2 api, exchange 2007, windows/.net and linux/mono2.10.2

using the EWS 1.2 api to extract attachments from exchange gives different results on .net/windows as on mono/linux.

the files differ at byte 8192, 16384, 20480

So first after 8k block, then again after next 8k block and then 4k block again?!

```
fileAttachment.Load();

byte[] buffer = fileAttachment.Content;
Console.WriteLine(buffer[8191]); //windows -> 50  | linux -> 50
Console.WriteLine(buffer[8192]); //windows -> 9   | linux -> 59
Console.WriteLine(buffer[8193]); //windows -> 54  | linux -> 44
```

I put the

```
service.TraceEnabled = true;
```

so i can look at the soap message. there i find the content as a base64 string.
i converted the base64 string online with [this online base64 decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) and the attachment returns perfect.

The size of the buffer on linux is smaller than on windows when using the EWS API.

So there must be something wrong with converting base64 string linux/mono!?

Comment: Please specify the version of Mono you are using - this might be a bug in a particular release.

Comment: version 2.10.2 - I can't find anything related to this issue

Comment: made a [bug report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=762529)

Comment: Did a test with java version of EWS and this works perfect. too bad for c#/mono

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see the same thing with both Mono 2.10.8.  I have investigated a bit more and filed a new bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9457